# redirect to URL name [dot]com to WWW[dot]URL name [dot]com

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

i m developing a website and hosted on server. i just want if some one write in browser 
 **URL name [dot]com** it will redirect to **WWW[dot]URL name [dot]com** is it possible to some
**I I S** setting or some other way . i goggled a lot but can't find any way to do that.if any one have any idea so please let me know

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Try Url Rewriting for this.If your IIS wasn't installed with Rewrite module, go to [this](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) page to download it.

See this StackOverFlow [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036542/append-www-in-url-for-hosted-asp-site-i-e-no-iis-access) for more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036542/append-www-in-url-for-hosted-asp-site-i-e-no-iis-access).

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="*" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.YourDomain.com" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.YourDomain.com/{R:1}" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: I m All ready doing URL rewriting using URL mapping i just want if user just type in browser URL like XYZ.COM it will redirect to WWW.XYZ.COM do u have any idea how this will be implemented..

Comment: For the same use this setting in web.config

Comment: ok i will try n let u know.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036542/append-www-in-url-for-hosted-asp-site-i-e-no-iis-access

Comment: thanks Subin jacob for your guidance above link give me solution to this problem...

Comment: Then, mark as your answer